# Should I use OAuth or JWT?

Tags: security, oauth, jwt

Im building a REST services for existing product. Now to authenticate these, there needs to be some mechanism. To give specifications, I have a Db which stores userid and password . I have to authenticate using these credentials.

In above should I use OAuth or JWT? I prefer to use JWT to generate token first and pass token along every request.

Also From my understanding, I understand OAuth should be used when you have multiple consumers like games/apps using Facebook login. In my case, I don't have any have multiple consumers.

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

Although it is true that OAuth is an authorization framework, it does help with JWT.  JWT is a token specification, meaning, how you manage and issue tokens is largely left undefined.  For instance, when your token reaches it's expiration, do you want your user to be abruptly logged out?  By default, if you're using tokens with a certain duration, this will happen if you're checking for expired tokens, which you should be doing.

An OAuth Authentication server can serve the purpose of issuing an Access Token in JWT, and a Refresh Token.  The access token will be included in every request, and the refresh token can be used when the access token is expired or about to expire to acquire a new access token.  This is useful when taking into account the potential need to revoke a users access to your application.  If you set a short access token life, then you'll be able to revoke access more quickly by removing their refresh token.

The technologies are different and not directly comparable because they solve different problems and are intended for different uses.

Comment: Thanks @blur0224, so in my case, should I use OAuth  for authenticating users? As you mentioned OAuth is authorization framework, so do i need to implement whole OAuth framework for my usecase or is there any other alternative?

Comment: Yes, the OAuth server can validate the users credentials against a db and issue a token.  OAuth2 has an Authorization Server that would be useful for implementing the work flow for issuing and refreshing JWT tokens.  You can implement just JWT and then add in the OAuth2 Auth Server to improve/extend authorization to your needs.

Comment: I'm still confused if i had to authenticate users against credentials stored in database why should i should i implement OAuth. I generate JWT  token after authenticating users credentials and then users could use this token along every request till it expires. Pls correct me if i'm missing anything here..

Comment: To clarify, I'm saying part of the OAuth work flow could be issuing an access AND refresh JWT token, which may include authentication against a database.  The JWT would be used on every request after that until it expires.  Then a refresh token can be used to get a new access token.  OAuth in this case is providing the work flow necessary for the refresh token.  If you don't want that behaviour, you can issue your own JWT token with a standard library after authentication.

Comment: Thanks blur0224 for your input. To reframe my question my application do not have any OAuth Provider. Since my application is stand-alone, i'm not sure how will implement a OAuth mechanism, i just need a secured way to call my application functionality using REST. Also if i implement OAuth how will i generate clientId and clientSecret. Do i need to hardcode them?

Comment: At this point I'd recommend opening a new question where you include more details about what technology stack you're using.  If you're only looking to secure a rest API and don't have security concerns with a long lasting token, just using JWT is a completely valid solution.  If you were to setup an OAuth Server, you would define your client ID and secret.